# Computing a certain definite integral of an even function knowing another one

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is a continuous even function such that

$$\int_0^3 f(x)\ dx = -4 $$

then
$$\int_{-3}^{3} (5f(x) + 1)\ dx =\ ? $$

I keep getting $-39$ but it’s the wrong answer.
Any help would be awesome

Comment: Hi, Jake! Since you've been a member here for more than a year, you might get more helpful responses if your posts reflect that. To improve your posts, you can use MathJax to help in the presentation of formulas, as well as using a more-descriptive title so others can search for this particular type of problem as well.

Comment: I think you might have forgot to integrate the 1.

Comment: You have $\int_0^3 f(x) dx = -4$ and need to know $\int_{-3}^3 f(x) dx$. Since $f(x)$ is an even function you can use $\int_{-3}^0 f(x) dx = ?$ and $\int_{-3}^3 f(x) dx = ?$. I seem to get the required integral as $5 \times (-8)+ 6$

Comment: I thought I understood but I still don’t follow where the “+6” comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f$ is even,
$$\int_{-3}^3 f(x)\ dx = 2 \int_0^3 f(x) \ dx = 2(-4) = -8, $$
so that
$$\int_{-3}^3 5f(x)\ dx = 5\int_{-3}^3 f(x)\ dx = -40. $$
Hence
$$\int_{-3}^3 (5f(x) + 1)\ dx = -40 + \int_{-3}^3 1\ dx = -40 + [x]_{-3}^{+3} = -40 + 6 = -34.$$